# How can session cache service data be stored externally?

Tags: ibm-cloud, session-cache

Cross-posting as advised from DeveloperWorks: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/212469/can-an-application-hosted-outside-bluemix-access-s.html

I am exploring a scenario wherein I have an existing Java application hosted on-premises outside BlueMix. I want to make it horizontally scalable. As part of this change I would like to know if I can provision a BlueMix Session Cache service to store the application's session state externally. The application will continue to be hosted outside BlueMix but use BlueMix Session Cache for session state management.

Comment: My original question has been edited twice and does not make sense after the edits. Any answers to this edited question will confuse readers in future. I request the editors to refrain from editing questions. Questions are asked to seek a solution to a specific problem. You have a choice not to answer the question. Editing the question itself and then answering it defeats the purpose of asking the question.

Comment: Seemed pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible at the moment.

Although a person can setup a Liberty runtime with the right connection information copied from VCAP and runtime variables, and use it to host a web application that use session cache client, this machine is outside Bluemix and won't be trusted by the network.  As a result, it won't be able to connect to the session cache within Bluemix.